# Pentaho - running a job in parallel

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a question. Maybe someone had a similar problem. I have a job which looks as below

[image]

When I launch job from spoon pentaho it's all work correctly.
When I launch job from .bat file then it doesn't work.
My .bat file looks as below

```
@echo off

call D:\Pentaho\Kitchen.bat /rep:git1 /dir:TestCase/Samples/example /job:Job_1 "/param:ENV=PROD" "/param:SOURCE=MAIN" "/param:path= D:\GIT_TESTS\pentaho\xlsx\MAIN" >> "D:\GIT _TESTS\ pentaho\xlsx\Logs\log_Job_1.log"
EXIT

@echo on
```

In file with log I getting:

```
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe

D:\Pentaho>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx4096m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -initialDir "C:\Windows\system32"\ /rep:git1 /dir:TestCase/Samples/example /job:Job_1 "/param:ENV=PROD" "/param:SOURCE=MAIN" "/param:path=D:\GIT_TESTS\pentaho\xlsx\MAIN" 
22:30:40,520 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
22:30:52,622 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 4 at D:\Pentaho\.\system\karaf\caches\kitchen\da ***
***   ta-16                                                                 ***
*** FastBin Provider Port:52904                                             ***
*** Karaf Port:8805                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9054                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
2022/11/04 22:30:53 - Kitchen - Start of run.
2022/11/04 22:30:53 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: C:\Users\USR_TST\.kettle\repositories.xml
2022/11/04 22:30:59 - Job_1 - Start of job execution
2022/11/04 22:30:59 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Parametr]
2022/11/04 22:31:00 - Parametr - Using run configuration [Pentaho local]
2022/11/04 22:31:00 - Parametr - Using legacy execution engine
2022/11/04 22:31:00 - t_GetJDBCStringParameters - Dispatching started for transformation [t_GetJDBCStringParameters]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Property ODS.0 - Finished processing (I=4, O=0, R=0, W=4, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Property SOURCE.0 - Finished processing (I=4, O=0, R=0, W=4, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Row denormaliser SOURCE.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=4, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Row denormaliser ODS.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=4, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Setting environment variables...
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Set variable USER_SOURCE to value [XXXX]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Set variable PASSWORD_SOURCE to value [XXXX]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Set variable URL_SOURCE to value [XXXX]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Set variable DRIVER_SOURCE to value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Setting environment variables...
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Set variable USER_ODS to value [YYYY]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Set variable PASSWORD_ODS to value [YYYY]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Set variable URL_ODS to value [YYYY]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Set variable DRIVER_ODS to value [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Finished after 1 rows.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables SOURCE.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Finished after 1 rows.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Set Variables ODS.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Test1]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Launched job entry [Test1] in parallel.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Test2]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Launched job entry [Test2] in parallel.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Test3]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Launched job entry [Test3] in parallel.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Test4]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Launched job entry [Test4] in parallel.
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Starting entry [Test5]
2022/11/04 22:31:01 - Job_1 - Launched job entry [Test5] in parallel.
```

Nothing more happens. I don't have idea what I do wrong.
Anyone have an idea? In spoon everythink works. For.bat file doesn't work.

I tried to find something on the Internet and solve the problem, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something is causing them all to lock up. We can confirm this if you run your Pentaho job but change the log setting to show more details.

To show more details in the log setting, when you click on the play button, you want to change the setting under "Log level:".

Post what you get and we can go from there.